# How do I install earlier versions of Haskell Platform and switch between them?

Tags: ghc, haskell-platform

I have installed this https://www.haskell.org/platform/#linux-generic Haskell Platform. The problem is it comes with ghc version 8.2.1.

How do I install an earlier version of Haskell Platform so that I can use older, bug-free ghc if I need it?

I can see prior versions available.
https://www.haskell.org/platform/prior.html
So the question remains, how do I make them peacefully coexist on my system?

activate-hs doesn't seem to work, so please tell me how do I switch defferent Haskell Platforms?

Just installing the Haskell platform has updated the links in /usr/local/bin.
So I guess my question is almost solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`activate-hs` should work for the most recent releases of the platform. If it does not, it would be good to know why.

Additionally, you can specify the `-w` or `--with-compiler=`  in either `cabal new-build` or `cabal configure` to give a path to a different ghc to use. That lets you sidestep moving symlinks around (the activate-hs solution) and just pick a ghc to use directly.